# Order By problems

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

As part of a query I have the following (I'm sill wearing the learner badge!) ...

```
SELECT 
    Main.Ax,
    Main.Ay,
    (select Astr from Afull where Avalid = Main.Ax) as AxStr,
    (select Astr from Afull where Avalid = Main.Ay) as AyStr,
    Switch(AxStr>=0, AxStr,AxStr<0,0,isnull(AxStr),0) 
    + Switch(AyStr>=0, AyStr,AyStr<0,0,isnull(AyStr),0) as AStrTotal
FROM Main
```

However, I have a problem when I try to include `Order By 5 Asc` in that it doesn't work. I'm guessing this has something to do with the 2 previous subqueries (then AStrTotal adds them together).

Additionally, is it possible to refer to alias field positions (5, above, for AStrTotal) without having to use the absolute position?

**EDIT: More background info...**

Table Main (primary database to be searched) comprises 2 fields Ax and Ay

```
Ax  Ay
1   6
5   9
3   3
    7
5   5
7   2
2   
4   4
    3
6   5
7   6
```

etc.... Blank entries above are simply null values. Ax and Ay values can appear in either field.

Table Afull comprises 2 fields called Avalid and Astr...

```
Avalid  AStr
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Field Astr is initialised to Null at the start of each run. 
The first use of this table is to store all valid values for Ax and Ay in field Avalid. The second use is to allow for the selection, by the user, of search critera. To do this, table Afull is added as a subform in the user search form. The user then selects an Avalid value to search for by inputting any value >0 into Astr - next to the value to be searched. Later, the Astr value (variable number indicating strength) will be used in `ORDER BY`

An sql query string is then built up whose purpose is to return all records carrying any 'permutation' of user-selected Avalid values

**I've now reduced the original query to...**

```
SELECT 
        Main.Ax,
        Main.Ay,
        (select Astr from Afull where Avalid = Main.Ax) as AxStr
FROM Main
```

Then adding...

```
ORDER BY (select Astr from Afull where Avalid = Main.Ax) ASC;
```

But I get a syntax error in ORDER BY. Removing the brackets doesn't help.

Comment: You should be able to `JOIN`/`LEFT JOIN` (depending on whether you will always have rows or not) to `Afull`, which will _possibly_ be more performant.  A `MAX(...)`/`COALESCE(...)` would make your intentions more obvious, although I doubt it would help otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

copy the entire query to `Order by`

```
SELECT main.ax, 
       main.ay, 
       (SELECT astr FROM   afull WHERE  avalid = main.ax) AS AxStr, 
       (SELECT astr FROM   afull WHERE  avalid = main.ay) AS AyStr, 
       Switch(axstr>=0, axstr, axstr<0, 0, Isnull(axstr), 0) 
       + Switch(aystr>=0, aystr, aystr<0, 0, Isnull(aystr), 0) AS AStrTotal 
FROM   main 
ORDER  BY Switch(axstr>=0, axstr, axstr<0, 0, Isnull(axstr), 0) 
          + Switch(aystr>=0, aystr, aystr<0, 0, Isnull(aystr), 0) ASC
```

Or Use `Sub Select` and `order by` in `outer query`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT main.ax, 
               main.ay, 
               (SELECT astr FROM   afull WHERE  avalid = main.ax) AS AxStr, 
               (SELECT astr FROM   afull WHERE  avalid = main.ay) AS AyStr, 
               Switch(axstr>=0, axstr, axstr<0, 0, Isnull(axstr), 0) 
               + Switch(aystr>=0, aystr, aystr<0, 0, Isnull(aystr), 0) AS 
               AStrTotal 
        FROM   main) A 
ORDER  BY astrtotal ASC
```

even `Order by 5 Asc` should work

```
SELECT main.ax, 
       main.ay, 
       (SELECT astr FROM   afull WHERE  avalid = main.ax) AS AxStr, 
       (SELECT astr FROM   afull WHERE  avalid = main.ay) AS AyStr, 
       Switch(axstr>=0, axstr, axstr<0, 0, Isnull(axstr), 0) 
       + Switch(aystr>=0, aystr, aystr<0, 0, Isnull(aystr), 0) AS AStrTotal 
FROM   main 
ORDER  BY 5 asc
```

Comment: Does `Access` allow you to use an alias in `ORDER BY`, so you can write `ORDER BY AStrTotal ASC` in the last query?

Comment: @Barmar - I Don't think `Access` will allow to use `alias name` in `Order By`

Comment: Many thanks for everyone's help here. Unfortunately I get errors whenever I try to include an expanded version of the Select sub query in the Order By statement. I've expanded things a little in my original question, showing what I've tried.